# Почему не работает click()?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
@Test
    public void demoTest() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\astatico\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).sendKeys("vk.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"btnK\"]")).click();
    }
```

Всё хорошо работает до выполнения click(). Выдаёт исключение: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable

Answer (score 1):

Перед кликом добавь ожидания

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"btnK\"]")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил добавлением:

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

между двумя вызовами компонент.

Comment: sleep'ы лучше не использовать, используй неявные ожидания, как написал @Amerousful